# Reducing the scope of a synchronized block in Java unexpectedly corrupts my ArrayList, why is that the case?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, thread-safety

A bit late, I have a Christmas special for you. There is a Santa class with an `ArrayList` of presents and a `Map` to keep track which children already have got their presents. Children modeled as threads constantly asking Santa for presents at the same time. For simplicity, each child receives exactly one (random) present.

Here is the method in the Santa class occasionally yielding a `IllegalArgumentException` because `presents.size()` is negative.

```
public Present givePresent(Child child) {
        if(gotPresent.containsKey(child) && !gotPresent.get(child)) {
            synchronized(this) {
                gotPresent.put(child, true);
                Random random = new Random();
                int randomIndex = random.nextInt(presents.size());
                Present present = presents.get(randomIndex);
                presents.remove(present);
                return present;
            }
        }
        return null;
}
```

However, making the whole method `synchronized` works just fine. I don't really understand the problem with the smaller sized `synchronized` block shown before. From my point of view, it should still assure that a present isn't assigned to a kid multiple times and there shouldn't be concurrent writes (and also reads) on the presents ArrayList. Could you please tell me why my assumption is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens because the code contains a *race condition*. Let us use the following example to illustrate that race condition.

Imagine that `Thread 1` reads

```
`if(gotPresent.containsKey(child) && !gotPresent.get(child))`
```

and it evaluates as `true`. While `Thread 1` enters the `synchronized` block, another thread (*i.e.,* `Thread 2`) also reads

```
if(gotPresent.containsKey(child) && !gotPresent.get(child))
```

before `Thread 1` has had the time to do `gotPresent.put(child, true);`. Consequently, the aforementioned `if` also evaluates as `true` for `Thread 2`.

`Thread 1` is inside the `synchronized(this)` and removes the *present* from the list of presents (*i.e.,* `presents.remove(present);`). Now the `size` of the `present` list is `0`. `Thread 1` exits the `synchronized` block, while `Thread 2` just enters it, and eventually calls

```
int randomIndex = random.nextInt(presents.size());
```

since `presents.size()` will return `0`, and the `random.nextInt` implementation is as follows:

```
  public int nextInt(int bound) {
        if (bound <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(BadBound);
        ...
    }
```

you get the `IllegalArgumentException` exception.

> However, making the whole method synchronized works just fine.

Yes, because with

```
 synchronized(this) {
    if(gotPresent.containsKey(child) && !gotPresent.get(child)) {
            gotPresent.put(child, true);
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomIndex = random.nextInt(presents.size());
            Present present = presents.get(randomIndex);
            presents.remove(present);
            return present;
    }
 }
```

in the aforementioned race-condition example `Thread 2` would have been waiting before the

```
if(gotPresent.containsKey(child) && !gotPresent.get(child))
```

and because `Thread 1`, before exiting the synchronized block, would have done

```
gotPresent.put(child, true);
```

by the time `Thread 2` would have entered the `synchronized` block the following statement

```
!gotPresent.get(child)
```

would have evaluated as `false`, and consequently `Thread 2` would have exit immediately without calling  `int randomIndex = random.nextInt(presents.size());` with a list of size `0`.

Since the method that you have shown is being executed in parallel by multiple threads you should ensure mutual exclusion of the shared data structure among threads, namely `gotPresent` and `presents`. Which implies, for instance, that operations like `containsKey`, `get`, and `put` should be performed within the same synchronized block.

Comment: Now it is totally clear, thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks, make sure those kids get the presents :D